# Repeat sudo code until proper password is entered

Tags: command-line, sudo

How would you repeat a sudo code (e.g `sudo install app`) until the correct password is entered?

Comment: From a security perspective, this seems unwise.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know what you're doing, you should not do this, especially in a multi-user environment, otherwise, you're just exposing yourself to brute-forcing.

---

If you know what you're doing, the `sudoers` option you're looking for is `passwd_tries`. From `man 5 sudoers`:

> passwd_tries
>
> The number of tries a user gets to enter his/her password before sudo logs the failure and exits.  The default is 3.

So, you can set this to a higher value to meet your need e.g. in `/etc/sudoers` you can put:

```
Defaults    passwd_tries=100
```

to have 100 attempts prompts.

As a side note, always use `sudo visudo` to open `/etc/sudoers` (to ensure sanity checks), don't open it in manually in editor.